# How do you unequip a weapon?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In the loadout menu, the interface makes it pretty obvious how to equip your weapons. But since having additional weapons increases your weight and power recharge time, how do you actually unequip one? I am playing the PC version if that matters at al

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you choose which weapon of a particular type you want to equip, one of the choices should be to not equip any.

Answer (score 2):

On the Xbox I scroll to the left so that the weapon number indicator (X/X) reads 0/X and then hit accept.